# How to increase the size of pie chart

Tags: matplotlib

sales2 = sales.groupby(['State'])[['Sales2016']].sum()

```
sales2graph = sales2.plot(kind='pie', 
            labels=sales2['Sales2016'], 
            colors=['r', 'g', 'b'],
            autopct='%1.0f%%', # to get percentage and round off appropriately
            fontsize=10, 
            subplots='true')
```

[image: My image is below.I have added <code>radius=1800, frame=True</code> but couldnot help]

Comment: Use `figsize`  parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `figsize`:

```
sales2graph = sales2.plot(kind='pie', 
            labels=sales2['Sales2016'], 
            colors=['r', 'g', 'b'],
            autopct='%1.0f%%', # to get percentage and round off appropriately
            fontsize=10, 
            subplots='true',
            figsize=(10,8))
```